# error Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, poo, php7

pese ha haber buscado y de leer varias preguntas y respuestas similares no logro entender cual es la cuasa de ese error en mi codigo, pido muy amablemente de su ayuda.

tengo una clase conexion en la que realizo la conxion a la db y tambien tengo una clase usuarios en la que hago los insert select etc; el inconveniente que tengo es cuando trato de registrar a un nuevo usuario, obtengo el error que menciono en el titulo, este es mi codigo

conexion

```
public function obtener_resultados_cosulta($query)
    {
        $array_datos=array();
        $this->abrir_conexion();
        if ($result=$this->conexion->query($query)) 
        {
            while ($dato=$result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $array_datos[]=$dato;
            }
          $result->close();
          return $array_datos;
        }
        echo "No se pudo realizar la consulta";
        return NULL;
        $this->cerrar_conexion();
    }
```

esta es la clase usuarios

```
    class Usuarios{
        private $database;
        private $conexio_db;

        public function __construct(){
            $database = array('host'=>'localhost','usuario'=>'xxxxx','password'=>'xxxxxx','bd'=>'xxxxxx');
            $this->conexio_db=new Conexion($database);
        }

        public function agregarUsuario($email,$pass,$nombres,$apellidos,$pais,$direccion,$postcode,$ciudad,$provincia,$telefono)
        {
            $pass_hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $query="INSERT INTO usuarios (email,pass,nombres,apellidos,pais,direccion,postcode,ciudad,provincia,telefono)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt=$this->conexio_db->ejecutar_consulta->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param('ssssssissi', $email,$pass_hash,$nombres,$apellidos,$pais,$direccion,$postcode,$ciudad,$provincia,$telefono);
            $stmt->execute();   

        }
public function verificarEmail($email)
        {
            $query="SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email=?";
            $result=$this->conexio_db->obtener_resultados_cosulta->prepare($query);
            $result->bind_param('s',$email);
            $result->execute();

            if($result!=NULL)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```